# WPF - Templated Combobox's drop down won't open

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a very simple ControlTemplate for a control based off a combobox (I call it AutoComplete):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="AutoCompleteControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ctr:AutoComplete}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Calibri" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Whenever I apply this template to the control, the combobox's drop down refuses to open.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the drop down is contained in the original `ControlTemplate` of the control - which you overwrite - it is simply not there any more. Either try accomplishing what you want without overwriting the `ControlTemplate`, or build your own drop down.

Some hints: The `ComboBox` has a property `IsEditable`, which makes it so that you can write text into it. If you want to build your own drop down, look at the `Popup` control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#combobox-parts) with working examples     `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#combobox-parts`